# RxJava- Is cache() the same as replay()?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

I was wondering if there was a `cache()` operator that could cache x number of emissions but also expire them after a specified time interval (e.g. 1 minute). I was looking for something like...

```
Observable<ImmutableList<MyType>> cachedList = otherObservable
    .cache(1, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

This would cache one item but would expire and clear the cache after a minute.

I did some research and found the [replay](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/replay.html) operator. It seemed like it would fulfill this need but I have some questions. Why is it hot and needs to be connected? Does this make it different than the `cache()` operator? I know the `cache()` mimics a subject, but it does not require being connected.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`cache` and `replay` are meant for different use cases. Cache is an auto-connecting replay-everything container used typically for long-term replays. Replay can have more parametrization and can do bounded time/size replays but requires the developer to specify when to start. The `autoConnect()` operator lets you turn such `ConnectableObservable` instances to a plain `Observable` which connects to the source once a subscriber subscribes to them. This way, you can have a bounded and auto-connecting replay (requires RxJava 1.0.14+):

```
source.replay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).autoConnect().subscribe(...);
```

Comment: You should probably mention `autoconnect` is experimental

Comment: It is now more likely to become standard API: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/3391