# RxJavas Single. Where are its connected methods?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

Lets say I want to make a network call and use a rx.Single as I expect just a single value.

How can I apply something like `replay().autoConnect()` so the network call does not occur multiple times when I'm subscribing from multiple sources?
Should I use `toObservable().replay().autoConnect()`?

I assume there is a reason that the whole `publish()` `ConnectableObservable` chain is left out?

**edit: My question is not about how to convert it to a regular observable. My question is how to continue using the rx.Single the whole way down.**

Comment: (Sorry about that - I commented, then reread your question and realized my comment was irrelevant, and probably deleted my comment at the same time you were posting yours.)

Answer (score 2):

If you convert it to an `Observable`, use `.cache()` to limit the number of connections to one.

Comment: Cache is different from replay. With cache it is not guaranteed that a second subscriber receives the same results. Just that the reference is the same. Take this for example. It prints different values. https://gist.github.com/PaulWoitaschek/80ef58d766935d0f340d9b2ce7213b31

Comment: @PaulWoitaschek That link is about the `share()` operator, which makes sense; `cache()` however does re-send old items - see the [docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#cache())

Comment: Completely misread, thanks. Do you think there is a difference between cache() and replay().autoConnect()?

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522017/rxjava-is-cache-the-same-as-replay) tells it better than I can.

Comment: So you think there is no difference?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `Observable` method, you'll have to transform your `Single` to an `Observable` using `toObservable` method.

```
Observable<Object> obs = yourSingle.toObservable();
obs.replay().autoConnect().subscribre();
```

Comment: I wrote what you suggested in my question. But that's not really a solution as it defeats the purpose of rx.Single and is more a workaround.

Comment: Why it's a workaround ? Single only give you a subset of Observable operator. If you want to use Observable method, you'll have to transform your Single to an Observable.